# How can I get the value of column A adjacent to the first empty cell in column B?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using this script to find the last row containing data in column A on the Info sheet, then display this value plus 1 in cell B3 on the Data Entry sheet. It works great, you can see an example sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LWZZoEmeSNuGSi2sPx6l3QA6Gc6YFetfdcvatNIjfG8/edit?usp=sharing).

```
function AUTOFILL() {
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Info');
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Data Entry');
  var valueOfData = sheet1.getRange(sheet1.getLastRow(), 1).getValue();
  sheet2.getRange('B3').setValue(valueOfData + 1);
}
```

What would be the most efficient way to change this so that it finds the first empty cell in column B on the Info sheet, then displays the value of its adjacent cell A in cell B3 on the Data Entry sheet instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrating it into your code:

```
function valueNextToFirstEmptyCellInColumnB() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,2);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(!vA[i][1] && vA[i][1].toString().length==0) {
      //Logger.log(vA[i][0]);
      return vA[i][0];
    }
  }
  return sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow(),1).getValue()+1;
}

function AUTOFILL() {
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Info');
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Data Entry');
  var valueOfData = valueNextToFirstEmptyCellInColumnB();
  sheet2.getRange('B3').setValue(valueOfData);//was adding 1 twice
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Cooper, I'm trying to incorporate this into my existing script, but I am not having any success - I'm getting '1' as a result. I've added an example sheet, would you be able to take a look at it? The way it's set up, I should be getting the number 140 displayed in cell B3 on the Data Entry sheet when I click the AUTOFILL button, as that is the value in column A's cell next to the first empty cell in column B on the Info sheet.

Comment: Sure I'll take a look where's the link

Comment: Try it again.  I'm getting140 now.

Comment: I'm getting the correct result in the log, but how do I get it to show up in cell B3 of the Data Entry sheet? You can see what I've tried in my example sheet's script.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you! One last question - any idea why this isn't working for me? I'm trying to display the last number in column A plus one if there is no empty cell in column B, and don't understand what I'm missing here:
`...
for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(!vA[i][1] && vA[i][1].toString().length==0) {
      return vA[i][0];
    }
  }
  return sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow(), 1).getValue()+1;
}`

Comment: I fixed that problem.  The problem was this line: `var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow(),2);` It should have been this: `var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,2);` Sorry about that.  I also noticed I was adding 1 twice.  It's getting the correct number now.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much.